# Angular 2 detectChanges vs setTimeout()

Tags: angular, settimeout, angular2-changedetection

I'm facing an issue regarding angular 2 change detection.
I'm using a component which uses the 'onPush' strategy and I've noticed that it's child component don't update them self on update (They themselves also 'onPush') so I've added changeDetector.detectChanges() to my code and it caused `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.
I dag up a little bit and wound up doing

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
}, 0);
```

And the code worked just fine.
My question is why angular.detectChanges() cause this error and using setTimeout don't? If I understood currently the setTimeout should run changeDetection also so it pretty much the same, doesn't it?

Is it good practice to use the setTimout like that?

Comment: Hard to tell from your code snipped why `detectChanges` blows up. `setTimeout` runs change detection for the whole application and is therefore less efficient.

Comment: Hoo Well that make more seance to me now.. Because the all application is refreshed and not only the component tree it works... Thanks !