# How to use the timeout() in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, settimeout

Am setting a timeout in my code but i keep getting this error: Typescript Error
Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable'. How can i solve this? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
this.http.post(this.global.api_url + '/cancel_order', {id: product._id})
    .timeout(10000)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data.result.id != null && data.result.rev != null && data.result.ok == true && data.status == 201) {
            this.global.toast("Order canceled", "toast-error");
            let del_data = [{_id: product._id, _rev: product._rev}];
            this.orders.delCart(del_data);
            loader_send_1.dismiss();
            this.ngOnInit();
         } else {
             this.global.toast("Failed to cancel order", "toast-error");
             loader_send_1.dismiss();
         }
```

Comment: did you add the import `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'`

Comment: When using rxjs you have to import the operators you are using in each file.

Like so:
´'import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'´
´'import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'´

Comment: Thanks Rahul Singh, i added that and the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Faisal and Sebastian as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could either add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'`

OR

You could use the standard JavaScript `setTimeout()` function like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.http.post(this.global.api_url + '/cancel_order', {id: product._id})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
            if (data.result.id != null && data.result.rev != null && data.result.ok == true && data.status == 201) {
                this.global.toast("Order canceled", "toast-error");
                let del_data = [{_id: product._id, _rev: product._rev}];
                this.orders.delCart(del_data);
                loader_send_1.dismiss();
                this.ngOnInit();
             } else {
                 this.global.toast("Failed to cancel order", "toast-error");
                 loader_send_1.dismiss();
             }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks the import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout' worked for me

Comment: Don't use setTimeout as a wrapper! It cause a tick in you app and in this cause it's retardant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634031/angular-2-detectchanges-vs-settimeout